# Has Peter Parker ever eaten bugs?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

After being bitten by the spider, has Peter Parker ever **eaten** or **craved eating** bugs as a side effect?

Comment: Spider-man, Spider-man, eats whatever a spider can....

Comment: Seeing that the FDA has an acceptable level of "whole or equivalent insect parts" in food, Peter Parker and everyone else who has eaten anything once grown on a farm has eaten bugs.

Comment: @B540Glenn I'm not sure it's taking this question in good faith to not interpret it to mean "gone out of his way to eat bugs as would a spider in contrast to human tendencies"

Comment: In the Spider-Verse, when she was Spider-Man, River Tam did...

Comment: Web-swinging through a coastal city?  One imagines that his full-face mask was inspired in no small part by sand flies.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Catches flies, any size, eats them all without a spice...

Answer (score 28):

Spiders-Man of Earth-11580 almost certainly has.

> [image: Comic panels showing Spiders-Man of Earth-11580 transcribed below with the right panel showing him made up of spiders]
>
> #### Spiders-Man.
>
> Thousands of spiders that believe they are Peter Parker of Earth-11580.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure if this counts as "Peter Parker" considering the quote in the image but it is certainly a borderline case.

Comment: I don't know if this counts as *Peter Parker*, but it's amusing.

Comment: This here is some nightmare fuel I did not need. Well done.

Comment: Spiders-man definitely eats people not bugs.  Spiders-man means the other way around.  Yes, that is it.

Comment: What is happening in the right panel?

Comment: @Amy The spiders are splitting up.

Comment: @RossThompson Ooooh, Spider**s**-Man.  He's physically made of spiders.  Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

Depending on how much you're willing to look into it, kinda? In *The Amazing Spider-Man*, Peter catches a fly (0'15 in the clip below), and is seen licking his fingers at 0'30. Might not be actual craving though, perhaps just uneasiness.

Comment: Judging from his overall behavior, I'd say he wasn't intentionally tasting his fingers

Answer (score 21):

In *Spider-Man: The Animated Series* Spider-Man mutates into his final mutation form from the initial spider bite and becomes Man-Spider. Presumably he ate some bugs in this form even if we don’t explicitly see it, that I remember.

[image: full view of Man-Spider from the cartoon]

Comment: Even if we did see this form eating bugs, I'd have trouble still considering this thing as Peter.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd It is Peter, just mutated. He later reverses it.

Answer (score 7):

According to *Spider-Man Deadpool* issue #5, yes! It’s stated twice, from both Peter and Deadpool’s perspective, that while trapped in Tabula Rasa he ate insects— he frames it as something simply done to survive, but in Deadpool’s retelling he seems to think he enjoyed it, though whether that’s true or not is up for speculation. Take it how you will!

[image: Deadpool and Spider-Man fighting an unseen foe, their conversation is quoted below]

> **Spider-Man:** Wade, seriously. What are you talking about?
> Last time I saw you we were in Tabula Rasa. Do you know Husk and I were stuck in there for 36 hours?
> We had to eat bugs.
> BUGS.
>
> **Deadpool:** I... wait. Are you serious?
>
> **Spider-Man:** Who lies about eating bugs? Who does that?

[image: Spider-Man and Deadpool having the same conversation as above but from Wade's recollection, it is quoted below. Spider-Man is swinging on a web towards the foe, Wade holds a massive weapon]

> **Spider-Man:** We had to eat bugs.
> To be honest, they were delicious, but that is not the point.

Comment: This seems more like a necessity than a craving

Answer (score 1):

One of the earliest incarnations of the web-slinger in television was [Supaidaman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(Japanese_TV_series)):

Rather than Peter Parker the student/freelance photographer, this one was a motorcycle racer called Takuya Yamashiro. Living his whole life in Japan and having been born decades ago, it is quite possible that Yamashiro at least once tried some of the local insect-based dishes, such as 稲子 (inago, which is actually grasshopper), 蜂の子 (hachi no ko, bee larvae) and 蚕のさなぎ (kaiko no sanagi, silk pupae).